# Evento Click Javascript se ejecuta solo

Tags: javascript, eventos, click, ar.js

Estoy intentando crear un listener en Javascript, y en cualquier browser del ordenador funciona perfecto, pero cuando ejecuto la web desde un móvil, el evento de click se ejecuta sólo, cuando quiere, sin haber hecho click...

```js
animatedMarker.addEventListener('click', function(ev, target) {
  //Código a ejecutar onClick.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene stats embedded arjs='debugUIEnabled: false;'>
  <a-marker markerhandler emitevents="true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" type='pattern' preset='custom' url='/pattern.patt' id="animated-marker">
    <a-gltf-model src="/ModelosPruebas/Ani/PruebaAni.gltf" animation-mixer="clip: SubeBaja;" id="animated-model"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-gltf-model src="/ModelosPruebas/TextoPrueba.gltf" id="animated-model-2"></a-gltf-model>
  </a-marker>
  <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Estoy programando una web AR, con [AR.js](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/), en este caso la idea es que al tocar/clicar el modelo 3D, se inicie una animación.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando? (No controlo mucho Javascript)
Gracias!

Comment: que elemento del DOM  es `animateMarker` ?

Comment: Un a-marker (de aframe-ar): Este es el html:<a-scene stats embedded arjs='debugUIEnabled: false;'>
        <a-marker markerhandler emitevents="true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" type='pattern' preset='custom' url='/pattern.patt' id="animated-marker">
            <a-gltf-model src="/ModelosPruebas/Ani/PruebaAni.gltf" animation-mixer="clip: SubeBaja;" id="animated-model"></a-gltf-model>
            <a-gltf-model src="/ModelosPruebas/TextoPrueba.gltf" id="animated-model-2"></a-gltf-model>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>  
    </a-scene>

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y añade el código a la pregunta, por favor. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para conocer el sitio y entiendas qué es un [mcve]

Comment: editado está :)

Comment: He convertido tu código en un snippet, espero te ayude a obtener más respuestas